# How to detect "swipe from edge" on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8

Here's a question - when using Windows 8 Metro applications we use swipe from edge gestures to show previous apps, charms bar or app bar.

How to detect similar gesture in Windows Phone 7 in case I want to implement similar app bar behavior? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we do with SurfCube is we added a transparent Border to the edges of the screens with a width of 5 pixels (could be more though). A MouseButtonDown event on these Borders should do the trick. Make sure that the Border is on top in z-order.

Be careful though: if you want a swipe down gesture, turn off the system tray as that steals the focus and the Border won't receive the event.